# DXF file's circle coordinates changed its sign in text data

Tags: autocad, cad, dxf

When [this ASCII .dxf file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/c0ma30zrqecx0v5/circle-between-lines.dxf?dl=0) is opened in software like AutoCAD, (x,y)coordinate of circle-center is positive signed. But, when I read the file in text data using note++ software, x coordinate of circle changed its sign to negative(at line number 5250) while line coordinates remains the same, that is, the circle origin changes from (91.7577, 103.4859) to (-91.757655,103.48592) in text. I have tried other dxf file's including circles and lines, but there is no changes in sign. Is there something that triggered to change the sign of x in circle while reading the data in text?

In DraftSight Software, the circle is between two vertical lines, but when I take the coordinates of entities from text data and plot in Geogebra, the circle is outside the two vertical lines.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the normal (code 210). May be it's reversed (0 0 -1). Also if you circle is in the BLOCKS section, it can be part of a block inserted with a negative scale.

Comment: The circle is not in BLOCKS, it's in ENTITIES section. For the normal, value for x is 0,  
`AcDbCircle
 10
-91.757655
 20
103.48592
 30
0.0
 40
1.988072
210
0.0
220
0.0
230
-1.0
  0
ENDSEC`. So (code 230) is supposed to be reversed as (0 0 -1)?

Comment: No the defaut value for 230 is 1.

Comment: Center is in OCS/ECS not WCS

Comment: Normally, I do not see the code (210 x 220 y 230 z) in text files. I take the center point from the code (10 x 20 y), does it related to OCS/ECS? I only have DXF reference from autodesk and do not fully understand the details of those abbreviations.

Comment: In the DXF reference, look at chapter 10, Object Coordinate Systems (OCS) section.

Comment: According to the explanation in chapter 10,
    given normal vector at Z-axis,  N = (0 , 0, -1); //from (code 230)
    Nx = 0; //from (code 210)
    Ny = 0;//from (code 220)    
    default WCS at Y-axis, Wy = (0, 1, 0);
    default WCS at Z-axis, Wz = (0, 0, 1);
    If (abs (Nx)  < 1/64) and (abs (Ny) < 1/64) then
         Ax = Wy X N = (0, 1, 0) X (0, 0, -1) = (-1, 0, 0)
    otherwise,
         Ax = Wz X N 
Finding Ay,
    Ay = N X Ax = (0, 0, -1) X (-1, 0, 0) = (0, 1, 0) 
So, (x,y) coordinate changes  to  (-x,y) in text data.

Answer (score 1):

It all has to do with the concept of **Extrusion**. If you list your CIRCLE inside AutoCAD you will get this information:

```
  CIRCLE    
  Layer: "12"
  Space: Model space
  Color: 3 (green)    
  Linetype: "Continuous"
  PlotStyleName: Color_3
  Material: ByLayer
  Handle = a2
  center point, X=  91.7577  Y= 103.4859  Z=   0.0000
  radius    1.9881
  Extrusion direction relative to UCS:
     X=   0.0000  Y=   0.0000  Z=  -1.0000
     circumference   12.4914
              area   12.4169
```

Notice this bit:

```
  Extrusion direction relative to UCS:
     X=   0.0000  Y=   0.0000  Z=  -1.0000
```

That shows you it is extruded. These extrusion factors are stored in the drawing using DXF codes **210**, **220** and **230**. In your case:

```
210
0.0
220
0.0
230
-1.0
```

You will find in AutoCAD that 2D entities are often extruded and it is usually indicated in the help documentation.

All DXF group codes are described [here](http://www.autodesk.com/techpubs/autocad/acad2000/dxf/group_codes_in_numerical_order_dxf_01.htm). I think you will also find it most useful to read up on the Object Coordinate System (OCS) [here](http://www.autodesk.com/techpubs/autocad/acadr14/dxf/object_coordinate_systems_40ocs41_al_u05_c.htm). This latter link explains all about the extrusion:

[image: Screenshot of the article]

Hope this helps.